# How to check if a count statement returns a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

This is likely very easy, I haven't used sql in a while and have run into this problem.  Basically, as part of a larger statement I only want to return a row from a select statement if a count from an inner select statement is equal to 3.  How do I do that?

For example...

```
select rev.name, s.title 
from reviewer rev, song s, rating r 
where (r.rID = rev.rID) and (r.mID = s.sID) and ...[rest goes here];
```

Where the 'rest' is that I only want to return when reviewer `rev` has reviewed song `s` twice, and r.value was larger the first time (we denote first time as the one with the oldest `r.date_of_rating`.

This is clearly a count and compare, but I don't know how to lay it out in proper SQL syntax.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @marc_s thanks for that.  Like I said, been a while :)  Any suggested improvements overall are appreciated as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure your example gives enough info.

But it sounds like you need a 'HAVING' clause.

e.g.

```
SELECT rev.name, s.title, count(r.mId)
FROM reviewer rev, song s, rating r 
WHERE (r.rID = rev.rID) AND (r.mID = s.sID) 
GROUP BY rev.name, s.title
HAVING count(r.mId) = 3
```